# Android - imageView don't have colorAccent color on KitKat

Tags: android, imageview, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I made two `imageView` that, when clicked, they take `colorAccent`'s color. This seems work on Lollipop and on Marshmallow, but not on KitKat. Plus, when they're not clicked, they should be grey but on Kitkat they're always black. Here's an example:

[image]

Here's my code:

COLORS.XML

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="itemNotSelected">#bdbdbd</color> <!-- this is GREY -->
```

An example on how I'm trying to change color when I click on `imageView`:

```
if(REPEAT_CLICKED == REPEAT_DISABLED) {
                REPEAT_CLICKED = REPEAT_ALL;
                mRepeatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_repeat_all);
            }
```

vector_repeat_all.xml:

```
<vector android:height="96dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="96dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent" android:pathData="M7,7h10v3l4,-4 -4,-4v3L5,5v6h2L7,7zM17,17L7,17v-3l-4,4 4,4v-3h12v-6h-2v4z"/>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Kit Kat doesn't support vector drawables. Are you using the support library?

Comment: Yup, in fact I can actually see vector drawables, even if not in the designed color

Answer (score 0):

Move your desired color to `android:tint` and let the path be any solid color.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="?colorAccent"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="96dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M7,7h10v3l4,-4 -4,-4v3L5,5v6h2L7,7zM17,17L7,17v-3l-4,4 4,4v-3h12v-6h-2v4z"/>
</vector>
```

This will work on API 21 and above out of the box and below API 21 if:

- You assign the image via `app:srcCompat` on an `ImageView` in XML layout inflated by AppCompat
- Call `setImageResource(int)` on an `ImageView` inflated by AppCompat
- Call `setImageResource(int)` on a `new AppCompatImageView(...)`

Source: This is how AppCompat does it internally.

Comment: Did you write `new ImageButton(...)`? Fix it to `new AppCompatImageButton(...)`.

Comment: I tested it on support libs version 24.1.1. What version do you use?